# Why does comparing frozen Gem versions fail?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am writing something in Ruby that needs to compare versions in order to determine whether or not something needs to be updated.

But when I run `current_version <=> desired_version` and at least one of the versions is frozen, I get:

```
    4: from .../ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:344:in `<=>'
    3: from .../ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:371:in `canonical_segments'
    2: from .../ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:393:in `_split_segments'
    1: from .../ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/version.rb:387:in `_segments'
FrozenError (can't modify frozen Gem::Version)
```

According to [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Version.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), the source code is this:

```
def <=>(other)
  return unless Gem::Version === other
  return 0 if @version == other._version || canonical_segments == other.canonical_segments

  lhsegments = _segments
  rhsegments = other._segments

  lhsize = lhsegments.size
  rhsize = rhsegments.size
  limit  = (lhsize > rhsize ? lhsize : rhsize) - 1

  i = 0

  while i <= limit
    lhs, rhs = lhsegments[i] || 0, rhsegments[i] || 0
    i += 1

    next      if lhs == rhs
    return -1 if String  === lhs && Numeric === rhs
    return  1 if Numeric === lhs && String  === rhs

    return lhs <=> rhs
  end

  return 0
end
```

I don't see why this code would be mutating the state of the Gem. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you where: The `<=>` method calls `canonical_segments`, which calls `_split_segments`, which calls `_segments`. So *that's* where the mutation must be happening; not directly in the method you've copied in the post.

More specifically, [here's the offending source code](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/1890559695d244e3b130952cd824c0dd832c240a/lib/rubygems/version.rb#L369-L397):

```
  def canonical_segments
    @canonical_segments ||=
      _split_segments.map! do |segments|
        segments.reverse_each.drop_while {|s| s == 0 }.reverse
      end.reduce(&:concat)
  end

  protected

  def _version
    @version
  end

  def _segments
    # segments is lazy so it can pick up version values that come from
    # old marshaled versions, which don't go through marshal_load.
    # since this version object is cached in @@all, its @segments should be frozen

    @segments ||= @version.scan(/[0-9]+|[a-z]+/i).map do |s|
      /^\d+$/ =~ s ? s.to_i : s
    end.freeze
  end

  def _split_segments
    string_start = _segments.index {|s| s.is_a?(String) }
    string_segments  = segments
    numeric_segments = string_segments.slice!(0, string_start || string_segments.size)
    return numeric_segments, string_segments
  end
```

Comment: Ok, so the lazy loading doesn't play well with frozen objects?